# Using Sequences regarding a tetrahedron stack of oranges

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Let $S_n$ be the number of oranges visible on the three upward-facing sides of the tetrahedron. Derive a closed-form formula for $S_n$ and determine how many levels the stack would have to have before more than half of the oranges are hidden. $S_n = C_n$ for $n = 1, 2, 3.$

I have a general idea of how to determine the closed-form formula for a tetrahedron which I figured would be for $C_n$:

$$_{+1} = \frac{(+1)(+2)}{6} + \frac{(+1)(+2)}{2}$$

$$_{n+1} = (n+1)(n+2)(\frac {}{6}+\frac 12)
$$
$$=\frac{ (+1)(+2)(+3)}{6}$$

$$=\frac{′(′+1)(′+2)}{6}$$ where n' = (n + 1). For example: $C_1 = 1, C_2 = 4, C_3 = 10, etc.$

I am unsure if this $S_n$ closed form formula would be the same since it asks "visible on the three upward-facing sides of the tetrahedron". Would I multiply the formula I have above by $\frac 34$ ? How would I go about determining how many levels the stack would have to have before more than half of the oranges are hidden?

Comment: Each face has a triangular number of oranges. You can multiply that by $3$ for the three faces. *But* you have to subtract out the "edges": How many oranges are on each edge, and how many edges are there? *Then* you have to add back the top orange. This is an application of the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).

Comment: What would the formula look like for that? I don't understand how to derive it from the original one I have for Cn? @BrianTung

Comment: I wouldn't derive it from the original for $C_n$; I would employ the inclusion-exclusion principle. You want the oranges in the union of the three faces; call them $A, B, C$. Then use the three-way inclusion-exclusion expression in the page I linked to.

Comment: Why did you [delete the previous version of your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4475512/using-sequences-to-determine-number-of-oranges-for-a-tetrahedron?noredirect=1#comment9382516_4475512), rather than simply editing it? While some members of the site may be able to easily guess what you mean, the question would be improved by some context (what oranges?) and proper explanation of terms (what are $C_n$, $T_n$?).

Comment: You have given a definition for $S_n$.  However, you have not defined $C_n$ and $T_n$.  Please edit your question to do so.

Comment: @Brian, I think that's the hard way. Instead, consider that if you remove all the visible oranges from the $n$th pyramid, what's left is the $n-3$rd pyramid.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: [cue "I could've had a V8" theme] (ETA: I wonder if the question is in a section on inclusion-exclusion, though. That would be the only reason not to use your idea.)